# Need to replace regex with a callback function

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to highlight the text(abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 (a) (6)) with the searched string(abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 b).

I am using the below code.

```
text = "abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 (a) (6)";
const highlight = "abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 b";

const word = highlight.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
const regex = new RegExp(word, 'gi');

const highlightedText = text.replace(regex, (x) => {
return '<span class="highlighted">' + x + '</span>';
});
text = highlightedText;
```

This is working fine when the search string is "abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101" but not working when search string is "abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 b".

Comment: Could you explain the (a)  (6) b thing?

Comment: It would be better if you said, "I need a function that gets <this> as input and returns <this>". And add some input/output examples. This way, the community will help you not only create the function, but also run some tests on the values you provided to make sure it works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

to get matched words between two lines what you need is array functions not regex

```js
const text = 'abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 (a) (6)';
const highlight = 'abc subabc 100.200 § 200.101 b';

let matched = highlight.split(' ').filter(w => text.split(' ').includes(w));
matched = matched.join(' ')

const highlightedText = text.replace(matched, `<span class="highlighted">${matched}</span>`);

document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = highlightedText;
```

```css
.highlighted {background: yellow}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```